# Chart C# add Data Point in cubic bezier curve

Tags: c#, bezier, spline, microsoft-chart-controls

I have written a method to create a Bezier curve for rendering in a `Chart` control. I have a collection of data points which I retrieve from another method. I would like to form the Bezier curve on my chart to produce something similar to a spline, but instead I am receiving a blank chart. The code to produce the curve is:

```
public static double XChart(double t, double x0, double x1, double x2, doubl x3)
{
    return (double)(
        x0 * Math.Pow((1 - t), 3) +
        x1 * 3 * t * Math.Pow((1 - t), 2) +
        x2 * 3 * Math.Pow(t, 2) * (1 - t) +
        x3 * Math.Pow(t, 3)
    );
}
```

I then add the curve to the chart with the code below:

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(XChart(0.1, a, c, b, d), YChart(0.1, l, f, i, g));
```

Where `a, b, c, d, l, f, i, g` are the values I get from a list of data points.

```
List<DataPoint> dataPoints0 = new List<DataPoint>();
var a = dataPoints0[0].XValue;
var b = dataPoints0[1].XValue;
var c = dataPoints0[2].XValue;
var d = dataPoints0[3].XValue;
var l = dataPoints0[0].YValues[0];
var i = dataPoints0[1].YValues[0];
var f = dataPoints0[2].YValues[0];
var g = dataPoints0[3].YValues[0];
```

Now, suppose that:

> a=  4 , l= 0
>   b=  3 , i= 3
>   c=  4 , f= 5
>   d=  3 , g= 6

I should get the curve like this:
[image]

However, what I get on my chart is this:
[image]

I'm not sure why this is happening, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are those numbers meant to be part of a control point calculation? Chart splines take only  points on the curve and will create the bezier from them without any added control points. To get full control you would use GraphicsPath.AddBezier not MSChart.

Comment: It appears that what you've done is assigned a single point to the chart; to get your entire curve you'll have to get all points that you need from time value `0-1`. That's how the curve function works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though you're only adding a single point to your chart; to fix this, you'll need to add each point from your curve that you are concerned with:

```
for (float t = 0.0f; t < 1.0f; t += 0.01f)
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(XChart(t, a, b, c, d), YChart(t, l, f, i, g));
```

The example above iterates from a start time of `0` and adds 100 points to your chart using `0.00f - 1.00f`.

---

The Bezier curve function you've implemented gives you a specific point in your curve based on time. You can always write a helper method to give you all points by adding an argument for the number of points that should be returned:

```
public static double XChart(double t, double x0, double x1, double x2, double x3) {
    return (double)(
        x0 * Math.Pow((1 - t), 3) +
        x1 * 3 * t * Math.Pow((1 - t), 2) +
        x2 * 3 * Math.Pow(t, 2) * (1 - t) +
        x3 * Math.Pow(t, 3));
}
public static double[] XChart(double x0, double x1, double x2, double x3, int totalPoints) {
    List<double> points = new List<double>();
    for (float t = 0.0f; t < 1.0f; t += (1 / (float)totalPoints))
        points.Add(XChart(t, x0, x1, x2, x3));

    return points.ToArray();
}
```

You can then utilize this helper method to build your chart as below:

```
double[] xPoints = XChart(a, b, c, d, 100);
double[] yPoints = YChart(l, f, i, g, 100);
if (xPoints.Length != yPoints.Length)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("The number of points between axes must match.");

for (int i = 0; i < xPoints.Length; i++)
    chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(xPoints[i], yPoints[i]);
```

I would take a look at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Constructing_B%C3%A9zier_curves) regarding the construction of Bezier curves. I would start with the Quadratic curve, and then after understanding how it works I would progress to your representation of high-order curves.

> For quadratic Bézier curves one can construct intermediate points Q0 and Q1 such that as t varies from 0 to 1:
>
> - Point Q0(t) varies from P0 to P1 and describes a linear Bézier curve.
> - Point Q1(t) varies from P1 to P2 and describes a linear Bézier curve.
> - Point B(t) is interpolated linearly between Q0(t) to Q1(t) and describes a quadratic Bézier curve.

Comment: Thanks PerpetualJ . The code worked very good now it is able to draw the -